# Remove class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue when trying to remove a class in jQuery.

Checkboxes are in the following structure. When I click on the checkbox to check then it adds the class checkbox in span and shows the checkbox checked.

I want to add the condition *if checked checkboxes is greater than one* then do not add the checkbox class on next checkbox when we click on it or remove the class based on clicked checkbox.

I am using the following jQuery code but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("label").on("click", function(e) {
        var abc = $('.custom.checkbox.checked').length;
        if (abc > 1) {
            $(this).children('.custom.checkbox.checked').removeClass('checked');
            alert(abc); 
        }
    });
```

```html
<label for="field_422_10" class="foo">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Yoga-tai chi-pilates" id="field_422_10" name="field_389[]" style="display: none;">
    <span class="custom checkbox"></span>
    Yoga-tai chi-pilates
</label>
<label for="field_422_11" class="foo">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Yoga-tai chi-pilates" id="field_422_10" name="field_389[]" style="display: none;">
    <span class="custom checkbox"></span>
    Yoga-tai chi-pilates2
</label>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Are you saying that you only want to have one check box checked at a time?

Comment: $('.custom.checkbox.checked'), what are you trying to select?

Comment: Which would be a radio button.  As I do not see the `.addClass('checked')` line anywhere I cannot see the problem.

Comment: Do you try this? `$(this).children('.custom.checkbox').removeClass('checked');`

Comment: You need do that inside loop. That is the best way

Comment: when we click on checkbox then it add the class checked in span and show the checkbox checked

Comment: Sounds like you want radios instead of checkboxes?

Comment: I am counting the checked class to read checked checkboxes

Comment: But you want only one selected as @mplungjan is saying, then you need radios.

Comment: I want checkboxes. It is example. I want to set the condition to select maximum 10 checkboxes

Comment: Please include more code, the chunk you have supplied is insufficient to address your stated goals.

Comment: jQuery foundation.min.js is working in template for it

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to have max allowed selections for checkboxes. You can do it with something like that:

```
$("label").on("click", function(e) {
    var MAX_COUNT = 10;
    var input = $(this).find('input');
    var span = $(this).find('span');
    var checked_boxes = $('#myboxes').find('input:checked');

    if (checked_boxes.length > MAX_COUNT && input.is(':checked')) {
        // uncheck input
        input.prop('checked', false);
        // remove class from span
        span.removeClass('checked');
    }
    else {
        if (input.is(':checked'))
            span.removeClass('checked');
        else
            span.addClass('checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: However, if you only use `spans` to count checked checkboxes, you can remove it at all.